# Why does Docker invalidate the build cache after changing permissions on a file COPY'd with the --chmod flag?

Tags: docker, file-permissions

My working directory contains two files:

- `Dockerfile` given below

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
COPY --chmod=755 ./hello.txt /opt/
```

- an empty `hello.txt` file with `644` chmod permissions

I ran the following sequence of commands, using Docker `20.10.8`:

1. `docker build .` first build, nothing is re-used from the cache

```
#6 [2/2] COPY --chmod=755 ./hello.txt /opt/
#6 sha256:2cb62e01e8edffaed06aeda7d8fa85b5f89850564f7458ab0be5cbe3d90478bf
#6 DONE 0.0s
```

2. `docker build .` second build without any change, all layers are re-used from the cache

```
#6 [2/2] COPY --chmod=755 ./hello.txt /opt/
#6 sha256:7d6fd54f3d6cc543bd4d186861d7ae116c5ed16c7ebca40a37fdbe027bce9ecc
#6 CACHED
```

3. `chmod 777 hello.txt` change permissions from 644 to 777
4. `docker build .` => another build after changing permissions, `COPY --chmod` layer is not re-used from the cache

```
#4 [2/2] COPY --chmod=755 ./hello.txt /opt/
#4 sha256:3f74f87506d9be5cbb722a723bf1422ce0a24b538201d719f712bbb4915de5a6
#4 DONE 0.0s
```

Why is the command 4 not re-using the build cache like command 2, even though the permissions and the content of the file are identical in the image due to the `--chmod` flag in the `COPY` instruction?

Comment: Because the cache is keyed on the source file context, not on the contents of the image.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I get why it is the case for regular `COPY` statements without `--chmod`. However, is there a technical reason for Docker caring about the permissions of the source file to determine cache validity when using the `--chmod` flag of `COPY`? Aren't the source file permissions irrelevant if they are overwritten by the `--chmod` flag?

Comment: The point is that it doesn't check: it only checks for the modification time of the source files. If the source file has changed, the cache is invalidated. It's not looking at specific attributes (it doesn't know that "only the permissions have changed"); all it knows is "source file is newer than cached version". Maybe the permissions have changed. Maybe there's new content. Who knows?